# A question on conditional probability

Tags: probability, self-learning

Question:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables. The relationship between the two is as follows. If $Y$ is less than or equal to $1$, then $X$ is equal to $Y$; If $Y$ is more than $1$, then $X$ can be equal to $Y$ or $Y-1$. Then what is the conditional probability of $X$ being equal to $Y$ given $Y$, i.e. $\mathbb P(X=y|Y=y)$?

Here is how I consider this question. First I get the following result.
$$\mathbb P(X=y|Y=y)=\frac{\mathbb P(X=y, Y=y)}{\mathbb P(Y=y)}.$$
Then in order to find the numerator, I think I can use the law of total probability as follows.
$$\mathbb P(X=y, Y=y)=\mathbb P(X=y, Y=y|Y\leq 1)\mathbb P(Y\leq 1)+\mathbb P(X=y, Y=y|Y>1)\mathbb P(Y>1).$$
Does this make sense in general, please? It looks odd to me to condition on $Y$ again. Otherwise, is there a better way to find this conditional probability, please? In addition, I have difficulty in finding $\mathbb P(X=y, Y=y|Y>1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition,
$$P(X=Y\mid Y)=\mathbf 1_{Y\leqslant1}+p(Y)\mathbf 1_{Y\gt1}=1-q(Y)\mathbf 1_{Y\gt1}$$
where, for each $y\gt1$, $p(y)$ denotes the (unspecified) probability that $X=Y$ conditionally on $Y=y$, and $q(y)=1-p(y)$ denotes the probability that $X=Y-1$ conditionally on $Y=y$ (note that one needs the function $p$ to be measurable).

Answer (score 0):

We have that $y\le1 \implies X=y$.

So $\mathbb{P}(X=y|Y=y)=\begin{cases}
  1 & y \le 1\\
\mathbb{P}(X=y|Y=y>1)&y>1\\
\end{cases}$

Is $\mathbb{P}(X=y|Y=y>1)$ given?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Based on your comments, should I assume that it is OK to condition on $Y$ again, please?

Comment: And how to find $\mathbb{P}(X=y|Y=y>1)$?